# Creating a timeline using Xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin

Using Xamarin.ios,

given that you have a bunch of items where each item has a Content (string) and some metadata. (think Facebook log entry).

What would be the approach to implement a tableview that displays this data?

The problems I'm having is

A) Auto adjust the height of the UILabel or TextView to fit the dynamic text in Content
B) Docking metadata (a UILabel) at the bottom of the UITableViewCell
C) Calculating the entire row height in the TableDataSource

I don't need code examples, just some insight in what to study.

I'm using Storyboarding in XCode to build the UI.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A) Auto adjust the height of the UILabel or TextView to fit the dynamic text in Content`

You can use methods `SizeToFit()` and `SizeThatFits(SizeF size)`.

`B) Docking metadata (a UILabel) at the bottom of the UITableViewCell`

Check out [`Auto Layout and Constraints`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutConcepts/AutoLayoutConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH14-SW1). You can define, that the `Y` coordinate of a label should be something like `container.Bottom - label.Heigth - 20`.

`C) Calculating the entire row height in the TableDataSource`

You should do this in `GetHeigthForRow`. Just add up all the controls heights and spaces between the controls.